# microsoft odbc driver manager data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: mysql, database, asp-classic, odbc

I am trying to run a Classic ASP application on Windows 8.1. It keeps on failing with error: **data source name not found and no default driver specified**

I am using an Access database. I have the same problem using a MySQL database. I tried with both 32 bit and 64 bit MySQL drivers -- first installing one then uninstalling and then installing the other.

```
driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver};option=3;server=localhost;user=root;password=;DATABASE=test;
```

I'm using these MySQL ODBC drivers:

```
mysql connector 5.3.4 - win32
mysql connector odbc 5.3.2 - winx64
```

Comment: Have you given your website's IUSR account read/execute permission on the driver's dll

Comment: I made the question clearer by removing statements that had little to do with the problem. I also made the problem description more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

Access can't be accessed through the MySQL drivers (they're for MySQL not Ms Access), what you need is the Microsoft OLEDB database connections.

`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;`

Source; https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Also for MySQL, if you're running a 32bit MySQL server on a 64bit machine the standard ODBC management tool won't work since it's the 64bit version by default.

You'd need to install in on the 32bit ODBC manager here `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

Once that's done you'd need the following connection string to work with a 32bit DB on a 64bit machine. `Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};Server=localhost;
Database=myDataBase;User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;`

Source; https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-2/